# Observer, MVC, Singleton and Flyweight - similarities?

Tags: design-patterns

This is not really homework, but it is something I've been wondering about since I did not get an answer for these questions in school:

Observer Design Patterns is a pattern of its own, of course, but it can also be a part of MVC pattern/architecture. It's the "view" part of MVC - but I do not understand how exactly that is?

Also, Singleton and Flyweight are also two different patterns - but do they share some similarities? On an exercise file I got, it indicates that these two patterns share something?

If someone could explain it for me, I'd be very  grateful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me try to define what design patterns means.

Design patterns are recurring piece of codes recognised by developers, that helps them model and implement applications in a way that is more readable and reasonable.

So, by their nature, design patterns can also be changed and adapted in different ways depending on problems you are trying to solve and related technology you choose to use.

In my understanding of MVC, for example, the View is the Observer, while the Model correspond to the Subject that is observed by the View. Every time the Controller update the Model, the View gets notified of those updates and can render the changes on screen.

Singleton pattern instead, is a way to ensure that only one instance of a class is running in the entire application and that it is usually globally accessible from everywhere in the code.

Flyweight, basically say that you can separate the extrinsic part of a class from the intrinsic part, by creating two classes. This way, you can instantiate more objects containing only the state-dependant part of the class and share a single class that contains the essential behaviour.

How Singleton, MVC, Observer and Flyweight interact with each other is up to the developer who implement an application by applying this and more patterns.

Comment: How to write a question -> http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/